How Can I check the computer's date format in Python?
please help me. How can I check the computer's date format in Python, if the date format is dd/mm/yyyy then print number 1, if mm/dd/yyyy then print number 2. Thank you for your help.
I asked Copilot for help before, but it didn't work properly.
from dateutil import parser

def validate_date_format(date_str):
    try:
        parser.parse(date_str)
        return 1
    except ValueError:
        return None

input_date = input("Enter the date: ")
result = validate_date_format(input_date)
if result:
    print(f"Date format: {result}")
else:
    print("Invalid date format.")


It's ambiguous if you're using an actual date as opposed to a date format.  If it's 31/12/2024 vs 12/31/2024, great.  But what about 01/02/2024?  Could be Jan 2 or Feb 1.   cough ISO 8601

It will needed to be handled seperately for Window's vs macOS/Linux,
import locale
import platform
import ctypes

def get_windows_date_format() -> int:
    LOCALE_SSHORTDATE = 0x1F  # Constant to get the short date format
    buffer_size = 80
    buffer = ctypes.create_unicode_buffer(buffer_size)

    # Call Windows API to get the short date format
    ctypes.windll.kernel32.GetLocaleInfoW(
        ctypes.windll.kernel32.GetUserDefaultLCID(),
        LOCALE_SSHORTDATE,
        buffer,
        buffer_size
    )
    
    short_date_format = buffer.value

    # Determine the format based on the leading pattern
    if short_date_format.startswith('M'):
        return 2  # mm/dd/yyyy format
    elif short_date_format.startswith('d'):
        return 1  # dd/mm/yyyy format
    else:
        return 0  # Unknown or different format

def get_unix_date_format() -> int:
    # On macOS and Linux, we rely on locale settings
    locale.setlocale(locale.LC_TIME, '')
    formatted_date = locale.nl_langinfo(locale.D_FMT)
    
    # Guess format based on known patterns
    if '%d' in formatted_date and '%m' in formatted_date:
        return 1  # dd/mm/yyyy format
    elif '%m' in formatted_date and '%d' in formatted_date:
        return 2  # mm/dd/yyyy format
    else:
        return 0  # Unknown or different format

def check_date_format() -> int:
    if platform.system() == "Windows":
        return get_windows_date_format()
    else:
        return get_unix_date_format()

result = check_date_format()

if result == 1:
    print("Date format is dd/mm/yyyy (1)")
elif result == 2:
    print("Date format is mm/dd/yyyy (2)")
else:
    print("Unknown or different date format")


FYI: nl_langinfo not available in Windows.

Good point, updated to handle for window's seperately. Tested in Win11 & WSL2

You solved my problem. Thank you very much.

I don't think it's possible to check for the date format from just string input alone as there are cases where both date and month are less than or equal 12, making month and date impossible to differentiate from each other. However, if you just want to check for more obvious cases where date exceed 12 and recognize the string as format dd/mm/yyyy by default in other cases than you try parsing the date string to DateTime object in dd/mm/yyyy format first using datetime.strptime inside the ValueError try catch. If it raise an exception, then proceed to attempt to parse the string the the mm/dd/yyyy format
from datetime import datetime

def validate_date_format(date_str):
    try:
        datetime.strptime(date_str, '%d/%m/%Y')
        return 1
    except ValueError:
        datetime.strptime(date_str, '%m/%d/%Y')
        return 2

input_date = input("Enter the date: ")
result = validate_date_format(input_date)
if result:
    print(f"Date format: {result}")
else:
    print("Invalid date format.")


